# How to get push transition animation for two separate UIStoryboards?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uistoryboard, uinavigationcontroller

I have split my app into UIStoryboards representing the key components of that app.

I am wanting to move from Storyboard A (main) to Storyboard B.

Currently I transition from A to B like this;

```
let sb:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Second", bundle: nil)
let vc : SecondViewController = sb.instantiateInitialViewController() as! SecondViewController

// change to desired number of seconds
let when = DispatchTime.now() + 0.5
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

    // Your code with delay
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let window:UIWindow = appDelegate.window!

    UIView.transition(with: window, duration: 0.2, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionCrossDissolve], animations:{

    }, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> () in

        window.rootViewController = nil
        window.rootViewController = vc
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    })
}
```

But it doesn't have the same animation as a tradition view controller push as generated from a traditional UINavigation or storyboard segue.

My question is, how can I animate it so that the storyboard I am moving to animates like a UINavigation push?

Many thanks

Comment: In Storyboard A, can you just add a storyboardReference to StoryboardB and ad a segue?

Comment: But in storyboard A the segue has to connect to something; can you post a screenshot of what your solution is as I cannot see anything in xcode regarding references to other storyboards

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-9-staying-organized-with-storyboard-references--cms-24226

Comment: Many thanks for your help